# "Asking the driver" or "Asking to the driver"?

Tags: transitivity, indirect-objects, direct-objects

I've seen this sentence: "I'm asking the driver where we're going."

But I'd usually say: "I'm asking **to** the driver where we're going."

Are both forms correct? Do they have a change in meaning?

**EDIT:**

By the way, which sentences would be correct with the following verbs?

"I'm giving the driver some money" or "I'm giving **to** the driver some money"?

"What are you saying the driver?" or "What are you saying **to** the driver?"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct one is just 'ask'; 'ask to' is not grammatical.

There is also a usage 'ask of' - it's formal and a bit archaic, and basically means 'please'.  "I would ask of you that you show some respect at the funeral" means "Please show some respect at the funeral"

Comment: Is this a rule or does it vary according to the verb? For instance, should I say "I'm giving the driver some money" or "I'm giving to the driver some money"?

Comment: Oh, it varies according to the verb, quite a lot.  There are verbs that can have dozens of different meanings, depending on the preposition following them.  Go read the definition for *turn*, for example, and see how many prepositions it can take.

Comment: Yeah, prepositions are really complicating my life. Could you please help me with two more verbs, "say" and "give"? I've edited my question with the examples.  :)

Comment: I recommend reading and studying the dictionary entries, and _especially the example sentences,_ for the verbs [**_give_**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/give_1?q=give) and [**_say._**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/say_1) I _say_ "boo!". I say "Boo!" _to_ someone.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Yeah, I've read the entries, but I still wasn't sure about the correct forms. This can be pretty confusing. Thank you both for the replies!  :)

Comment: @EvertonLenger I think you may also be getting confused about prepositions when they are used with the indirect object.  "I gave the driver money" is the same as "I gave money to the driver".  In the first case, 'the driver' is the indirect object.  In the second case, 'to the driver' is a prepositional phrase that takes the place of the indirect object.

Comment: I will have to take a better look at indirect objects then. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that these are correct:

I'm giving the driver some money.

I'm giving some money to the driver.

What are you saying to the driver?

Comment: These were my opinions too, but it's great to confirm them. Thanks for your answer!  :)